# Prevent rollback in AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Currently, my CFN is in update_rollback_failed state and apparently its a dead end state. To continue, I have to continue the rollback which is not an option.

We pushed a CFN 3 months back and due to some issue we made some changes directly from the console (huge mistake) and now we were trying to sync what we changed in the CFN itself. Due to some issue the deployment failed and it started doing rollback. Luckily, the rollback failed because of some checks on kinesis side.

The CFN available on AWS contains old config which is catastrophic and would definitely lead to some significant downtime.

I have tried continuing the rollback ignoring the resources but it allows to ignore only those resources for which the rollback update failed. How should I get out of this situation?

Comment: If you are facing this situation on a production system, which I'm guessing, you do. I would definitely contact aws support and make them aware that you having an issue with potentially catastrophic consequences. Sometimes they are surprisingly helpful!

Comment: @Tommy I already did and they said there's no other way other than to proceed with the rollback : (    

Posted on SO to check if someone faced similar issue and came up with some workaround.

Comment: I wonder if you can add all the resources to a [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) so that CloudFormation doesn't try to delete the resources? (I would recommend testing it before doing it!)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah thought about that but I'll have to make that change in the CFN itself for which again, I'll have to continue the rollback.

Comment: Yes, but the intention is that the rollback doesn't delete anything if all remaining resources are listed in the DeletionPolicy. (Maybe. Please test.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a known limitation of CloudFormation and there is no work around to it. There is an [AWS blog post that mentions update_rollback_failed](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/recovering-aws-cloudformation-stacks-using-continueupdaterollback/) that confirms that this is something we can't do anything about, it says the following:

> When a stack reaches UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED, this means that the CloudFormation stack was attempting an UPDATE operation, the operation failed, and we began a rollback. An issue occurred that stopped CloudFormation from returning to the previous “good” state during the rollback. As a result, the stack can’t update and can’t roll back, thus it assumes this half-way state. The API then stops any further actions on the stack other than ContinueUpdateRollback and DeleteStack.